# Change in synthesis rate of a molecule changes equilibrium concentration

Tags: biochemistry, kinetics

I was reading the topic of 'The concentration of the molecule can be adjusted quickly only if the lifetime of a molecule is short' from *Molecular Biology of the Cell* by Alberts.

At the end of pg-837 (this part can also be found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26813/)), the author says -

> "In fact, after a molecule's synthesis rate has been either increased
>   or decreased abruptly, the time required for the molecule to shift
>   halfway from its old to its new equilibrium concentration is equal to
>   its normal half-life—that is, equal to the time that would be required
>   for its concentration to fall by half if all synthesis were stopped."

What do they exactly mean by 'shift halfway'? I am not able to understand quite clearly what the above sentence means. I hope some of you may be able to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: The term **equilibrium** is different from **steady-state** w.r.t chemical reactions. Steady state is the right term for the above example. Equilibrium is used in the sense of forward and reverse reactions in a single reversible reaction. The above example considers two irreversible reactions — production and degradation.*

> ... ... the time required for the molecule to shift halfway from its old to its new equilibrium concentration is equal to its normal half-life

This is not true if the degradation reaction is zeroth order or if these reactions are nonlinear. But for a linear production degradation set of reactions ($X$ is a biomolecule formed at a constant rate $\alpha$ and degraded at a first order rate  $\beta$ ), the reaction rate can be represented by the following equation.

$$\frac{d[X]}{dt}\bigg|_1=\alpha _1 - \beta [X]$$

At steady state $\frac{d[X]}{dt}=0$, which means $[X_{ss_1}]=\Large\frac{\alpha _1}{\beta}$

Half life as defined, by setting $\alpha$=0 and solving the differential equation = ${\Large \frac{log(2)}{\beta}}$

When the formation rate is changed to a new value:

$$\frac{d[X]}{dt}\bigg|_2=\alpha _2 - \beta [X]$$

and $[X_{ss_2}]=\Large\frac{\alpha _2}{\beta}$

From the above equation following equation can be deduced (by integrating the differential equation):

$$-\frac{1}{\beta}.log(\alpha _2 - \beta [X]){\large|}_{X_{initial}} ^{X_{final}}= t_{\frac{1}{2}} $$

when you substitute $X_{initial}=X_{ss_1}=\frac{\alpha _1}{\beta}$ and $X_{final}=\Large\frac{\frac{\alpha _2}{\beta} - \frac{\alpha _1}{\beta}}{2}$ (halfway between new steady state and old steady state)

you would obtain: $$t_{\frac{1}{2}}= -\frac{1}{\beta}log\left(\frac{\alpha _2 -\beta\frac{\alpha _1}{\beta}}{\alpha _2 - \beta \frac{\frac{\alpha _2}{\beta} - \frac{\alpha _1}{\beta}}{2}}\right) = \frac{log(2)}{\beta} $$